# Why passing different function types in called-by-name function still work?

Tags: scala

In `Scala`, defining a function whose parameter is called by name is like this:

```
def f(x: => R)
```

I think `=> R` means the a function whose parameters are empty and return value type is `R`. But when I pass a function whose type is not `=> R` into `f`, such as `R => R`, I find it still works. The example is like this:

```
scala> def foo(code: => Int) {
     | println(code)
     | }
foo: (code: => Int)Unit

scala> val bar: () => Int = () => 1
bar: () => Int = <function0>

scala> foo(bar())
1

scala> val bar1: Int => Int = myInt => 2
bar1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> foo(bar1(2))
2
```

Could anyone can explain it?

Comment: Could you post an example of code where an `R => R` is accepted when the argument type is `=>R` ?

Answer (score 2):

The `x: => R` in the function definition doesn't stand for `function without parameters which returns R`, but it means `an expression which, when evaluated, returns a value of type R` without specifying anything else about the expression itself.

Comment: Could you give reference link for your opinion?

Comment: Actually, you are both right. internally the expression will be converted to a function, so that the called function `f` receives as the parameter a parameterless function `x` returning `R`.